# Битрикс. Найти в списке товаров, товар с торговым предложением

Tags: битрикс

Нужно срочно найти во множестве товарах, исключительно товар с торговым предложением в списке товаров в администрировании, но когда я захожу в фильтр по этим самым товарам отображаются только фильтры по свойствам но нет допустим галочки "товар с торговым предложением". Как можно легко найти их все не делая этого в ручную, потому что там сотни товаров и по возможности не прибегая к коду, потому что там довольно хрупкая система.

Comment: Создать новое поле, обойти все товары 
Проверить наличие тороговых предложений и проставить им свойство вот этой функцией ```CCatalogSKU::getExistOffers($ID,$IBLOCK_ID); ```
Тогда не надо будет ничего переписывать.

Comment: не вручную и не прибегая к коду не получиться